# How to reduce the lethality of Strangelets?

Tags: internal-consistency, worldbuilding-process, weapon-mass-destruction

So, as far as science fiction is concerned, **Strangelets** are very potent.

They are so stable that they convert normal matter into strangelets as well, 100% conversion, emitting gamma radiation in the process. Because of that, they are likely to cause an “Ice-9” scenario, [where the whole world becomes strangelets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjqh.jpg).

However, assuming the world is advanced enough to store and produce it in the first place, maybe some world only wants to destroy, say, a mountain, a country, an asteroid, but never the entire planet. Is there a way to reduce the effects of the ‘strangelet bomb’, such that their area of effect is much reduced, i.e. like a reduced half-life or only being reactive to solids?

Comment: At the level of subatomic particles, where strangelets do their strangely warped mischief, there is no difference between solids, liquids, gases and plasma...

Comment: Nasty things, boosting them into the sun isn't going to help, nor neutron stars - maybe having a black hole handy would do the trick.

Comment: After reading the question and the (currently only one) answer I'm still confused on what a "strangelet" is. Maybe some sort of particle? And it...does what exactly - I can only infer that *maybe* you're talking about some sort of explosive device but I'm not sure. Perhaps "*strangelet bomb*" refers to the *effect* of using strangelets and they are actually delivered through some sort of particle cannon.

Comment: If the strange matter is electrically charged then we can repel it magnetically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If one existed, it'd be better than the strangelet device**

Strangelets, for all intents and purposes, are just gray goo, except they function on a sub-molecular level. That means that you'd need a device capable of destruction on that level to stop the spread. And if you have such a device, capable of destroying the strangelet spread, than just use that instead.

Comment: It seems like there is a template on this site most answers follow of "If you could, you wouldn't have to"

Comment: It seems to be a function of how answers work on this site. It we can solve a problem by addressing an assumption the question is based on instead of the question itself, it's something we'll gladly do.

Answer (score 2):

The long-term stability of strangelets has been hypothesised, but it might not be true. A strangelet suitable for use as a weapon needs to be stable *enough* to ingest and convert a useful volume of matter in the target before it decays. A gun capable of shooting a strangelet would be able to penetrate any armour within its range, and wherever the strangelet passed through matter intense amounts of gamma rays would be released but in a fairly short period of time the strangelet would decay into a bunch of other particles in a final shower of gamma rays.

Given that it isn't clear they're even possible in real life, you can handwave this as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a concept called [point zero energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) which is similar to what you describe.  The idea being that the universe as-is is not at it's lowest energy state.  This comes from the concept that even in a vacuum we can find phantom particles and consequently energy.

With enough energy, if you could convert spacetime to zero point energy (so a true vacuum with nothing inside), it would eliminate everything at that point outwards at the speed of light.  If you died to this type of explosion, you wouldn't even have time to react.  There are some theories that this is why we can't find life in the universe.  It is because they reach a point where they can generate the necessary energy and it destroys them completely (sobering thought, isn't it?).  The only reason we're still around is because the speed of light is a relatively slow thing in our universe.

That tangent aside, I think such a device would act like ice-9, but for literally any kind of matter.  Many things contain water, but at least with ice-9, you can prevent it from spreading by simply not letting it spread to a body of water.

This sounds like it would be very deadly indeed.  I have to agree with @Halfthawed on this one.  Gray goo at least would have an aspect of it that you could control, say, it can be disactivated on command.  These strangelets, even if you could slow or halt the conversion if say the temperature were really low, well you may be able to halt it on the surface like a spreading fire, but below the surface it would continue to convert rapidly making it uncontrollable just the same.

Comment: Any radio signals sent (deliberately or otherwise) by other intelligent species would be travelling as fast as the false vacuum collapse, and would arrive first. This isn't a good theory for the paucity of life in the universe.

Comment: Well, that must be lethal. But how much energy is even required to do this anyway, turn spacetime to ZPE?

Comment: @StarfishPrime That isn't an argument to say that radio signals wouldn't arrive here first, but rather that an alien species would destroy itself before it's capable of sending a more powerful signal.  I understand earth radio signals are so weak as to be basically nonexistent beyond Pluto.  What chance would we have to receive radio signals from a point even 10 lightyears away?

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @Harabeck In the same way yours is an answer.  I was agreeing with you.  My answer is "grey goo".  No need for the attitude.

Comment: @Neil Attitude? I'm just saying that your post is not very clear. Do the first two paragraphs have anything to do with your conclusion or the question? Why are they included? The third paragraph repeats information already in the question, and the fourth is just agreeing with a previous answer. I'm sorry if you see any criticism as "attitude", but I'm unsure what your answer is actually trying to accomplish.