# Feasibility of Neil’s Zero-Point Energy / False Vacuum Weapon

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapon-mass-destruction

So, I have made two threads, one about the applications of **Zero-Point Energy** (which I had no results).

The second, about how to [reduce the effects of Strangelets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/163844/how-to-reduce-the-lethality-of-strangelets/163873#163873), or a better alternative to Strangelets, I came across an interesting answer from Neil, the true weaponization of Zero-Point Energy.

*”There exists a concept called point zero energy which is similar to what you describe. The idea being that the universe as-is is not at it's lowest energy state. This comes from the concept that even in a vacuum we can find phantom particles and consequently energy.*

*With enough energy, if you could convert spacetime to zero point energy (so a true vacuum with nothing inside), it would eliminate everything at that point outwards at the speed of light. If you died to this type of explosion, you wouldn't even have time to react. There are some theories that this is why we can't find life in the universe. It is because they reach a point where they can generate the necessary energy and it destroys them completely (sobering thought, isn't it?). The only reason we're still around is because the speed of light is a relatively slow thing in our universe.*

*That tangent aside, I think such a device would act like ice-9, but for literally any kind of matter. Many things contain water, but at least with ice-9, you can prevent it from spreading by simply not letting it spread to a body of water.”*

Looking at this, it feels oddly similar to the concept of [False Vacuum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum), and both more or less coincide with each other.

I ask if the effects are possible, and the watts required for such a device, or even how such a potential device could operate.

Comment: This is a hypothetical concept - I don't think anyone would know how much power it would take or if this can even happen. If you're writing a story based on this concept,  feel free to just handwave everything.

Comment: It feels similar to the concept of a false vacuum because it IS the false vacuum concept.

Comment: Yes they are hypothetically possible. Vide @Ryan_L's comment about them being the same concept. This doesn't make it actually possible based on current knowledge -- only theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Question answered. All speculative physics of course.**

1) **If the effects are possible** - possible within the standard model physics, theoretically yes, but quite speculative as there is no evidence for such (and the first evidence could mean we are caught up in the vacuum collapse wave-front). There are calculation based om the standard model that put limits on the vacuum collapse stability question, but these cannot be used to settle the question at this time whether such a collapse is possible, even assuming the standard model applies under such conditions.

2) **The watts required for such a device**. Probably not the right question, you probably need energy density (instead of power). But, it is certain to be in excess of that from collisions of the [Oh My God Particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle). This was probably a proton travelling at *99.99999999999999999999951% of the speed of light*, assuming of course that a sufficiently bang could trigger the vacuum collapse.

3) **Even how such a potential device could operate**. Possible by going bang very intensely, or invoking [Clarkes 3rd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws), Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

If a bang could not trigger collapse, you would need negative energy density - another speculative concept. The only thing protecting us from this theoretical catastrophe is the large quantum fluctuation needed to temporary reduce energy below the standard zero point energy. A naturally occurring negative energy state in quantum theory that has not collapse the vacuum field yet to our knowledge.

You would have to engineer vacuum energy state far enough below the standard zero-point energy state to overcome the *energy hump* protecting us from the true zero point energy. We have no theoretical model for manipulating these quantum fluctuations today, and I would conjecture never, since such engineering would seem to be at odds with the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).

Or possible invoking sufficient negative energy density, needs Clarks 3rd law here too. Negative energy is a real thing in quantum mechanics, but no practical engineering theory applies yet for your doomsday device.

I am not a physicist, I went the engineering route. Assuredly not an authoritative answer, but I did my best to ground it in the science I understand (or at least think I understand).

Comment: A well-thought answer. Thanks.